# "grep -rn" only yields one of two expected results

Tags: linux, grep, recursive

I am trying to find all the files in a directory structure which contain a specific word, but it is not working correctly.

- For example: when run from the path `/Institute/IITDhanbad/`, the command

  ```
  grep -rn "Programmer" *
  ```

  giving result as

  ```
  BTECH/CompScience.txt:22:    Sudip is a Programmer
  ```
- However, when run from the path `/Institute/IITDhanbad/MTECH`, the same command gives

  ```
  CSP/Boys/Good/Electronics.txt:13:    Sourav is a Programmer
  ```

The problem is, that the expected result when running the `grep` call in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/` folder was to have *both* results, i.e.

```
BTECH/CompScience.txt:22:               Sudip is a Programmer
MTECH/CSP/Boys/Good/Electronics.txt:13: Sourav is a Programmer
```

What is going wrong and how to resolve this?

Some additional info:

- The file type and access permissions are:

  | File | Mode |
  | --- | --- |
  | `MTECH` | `drwxrwsr-x` |
  | `BTECH` | `drwxrwsr-x` |
  | `CSP` | `lrwxrwxrwx` |
- `ls -ld` in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/` path:

  ```
  drwxrwsr-x 4 suresh faculty 4096 Sep 16 00:53
  ```
- `ls -ld` in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/MTECH` path:

  ```
  drwxrwsr-x 4 suresh faculty 4096 Sep 16 00:53
  ```
- `ls -ld` in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/MTECH/CSP` path:

  ```
  dr-xr-sr-t 4 ganesh faculty 4096 Sep 12 20:58 .
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CSP` is a symlink (see `l` in `lrwxrwxrwx`). Apparently your `grep` does not follow symlinks with `-r`, except symlinks provided as arguments. When you do:

```
grep -rn "Programmer" *
```

in the parent directory of `CSP` (i.e. in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/MTECH/`, right?), `CSP` appears as an argument after the shell expands `*`. But if you do this one directory "higher" (in `/Institute/IITDhanbad/`) then `CSP` is not an argument, it's a symlink encountered by `grep` during its recursive scanning.

GNU `grep` works this way. Is your `grep` GNU `grep`? If so, see the manual for `-R`. `-R` is like `-r` but it *does* follow symlinks.

Note if you did `grep -rn "Programmer" .` in the parent directory of `CSP` then `CSP` would not appear as an argument. The usage of `*` was crucial for what you observed.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

[GNU grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dr) states that the option `-r` only follows the immediate symlinks (the ones given on the command line), but not the ones further away inside the directory hierarchy:

> **-r**
> **--recursive**
> For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command line, but skip symlinks that are encountered recursively. Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory. This is the same as the ‘--directories=recurse’ option

So, the directory CSP, being a symlink inside the immediately given directory MTECH, doesn't get traversed when searching for the given text.

**NB: Previous answer, prior to the clarification of the question:**

**Possible cause of the problem**

The subdirectory MTECH could not have execute permission bit set. For example:

```bash
$ mkdir -p one/two
$ cd one
$ cat <<EOT > test.txt
abc def
EOT
$ cp test.txt two
$ grep -rn def *
test.txt:1:abc def
two/test.txt:1:abc def
$ chmod -x two
$ grep -rn def *
test.txt:1:abc def
grep: two/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Admittedly, this would give an error message on stderr. However, if **grep is set up as an alias** to `/usr/bin/grep -s`:

```bash
$ alias grep='/usr/bin/grep -s'
$ grep -rn def *
test.txt:1:abc def
```

Which is the possible final piece of the puzzle.

**Solution**

Use `unalias grep` before running grep, or use `/usr/bin/grep` instead of just `grep`.

Comment: Do you think they changed the permissions of the directory between those commands? Since without the `x` bit on the directory, they can't change to the directory to run the other `grep` either.

Comment: @ilkkachu Possibly, with the one in the subdirectory being done first, followed by the `chmod -x` and then the grep in parent directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify your approach by simply executing your cmd as:

```bash
target_dir="/path/to/directory/of/interest"
[ -d "$target_dir"  ] && grep -rn -e "Programmer" "$target_dir"
```

or similarly to what you tried but including the test on the file operand being a directory:

```bash
target_dir="/path/to/directory/of/interest"
[ -d "$target_dir"  ] && cd "$target_dir" && grep -rn -e "Programmer"
```

using the fact that recursing (`-r`) with no file operand provided is the same as recursing from `$PWD` down.

Is this what you were asking for ?

Comment: I am asking why all the results are not displayed in '/Institute/IITDhanbad/' folder when I am using grep?